# `[バグ] -[status-completed]` でタグ付き質問をうまく検索できない

Tags: バグ, 完了, 検索

`[bug] -[status-completed]` であれば [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) not [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) と解釈してくれます:

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug+-status-completed

`[バグ] -[status-completed]` だと [バグ+-status-completed](/questions/tagged/%e3%83%90%e3%82%b0%2b-status-completed) と解釈されてしまいます:

https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%E3%83%90%E3%82%B0+-status-completed